# Elastic search filter facet using from and size parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I am trying to get the count in the previous pages of filtered documents in a facet.

Is that possible?

For example here I would like my previous_macs facets to count all documents before 20 that have the os_name: "mac".

```
{
    "from": 20,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": {
        "created_at": "desc"
    },
    "facets": {
        "previous_macs": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "os_name": "mac"
                }
            }
            // something here ? facet_filter maybe?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do it, but if you can formulate a filter that would reliably filter out everything except the first 20 records, you can use it as `facet_filter`. So, if `created_at` field is unique, you can use it to create a range filter that would include everything up to and including the 20th document. You can then use this range filter as a `facet_filter` for your facet.